# Nested MySQL Queries and Alphanumeric Ordering

Tags: mysql, alphanumeric, subquery

So, I've been trying to use nested MySQL Queries  in combination with alphanumeric ordering for a table, in my code for a while.

Take for example the following table:

```
Subprocess_has_Characteristic{
  ID (PK)
  SubProcessID (FK)
  CharacteristicID (FK)
}
```

The following are example values for the table:

**ID       SubprocessID       CharacteristicID**

---

ID1     SubprocessID1     CharacteristicID1

ID2     SubprocessID1     CharacteristicID2

ID3     SubprocessID2     CharacteristicID1

ID4     SubprocessID2     CharacteristicID2

...        ...                            ...

ID11     SubprocessID1     CharacteristicID5

---

This means we will need the following MySQL query to order the table alphanumerically and avoid the following: { ID1, ID10, ID11, ID2, ID3, ..., ID9} and get the following: { ID1, ID2, ..., ID9; ID10, ID11}

```
SELECT *,substring(ID, 1, 2) as bcd, 
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(ID, 2, 5),UNSIGNED INTEGER) 
AS num from `Subprocess_has_Characteristic` order by bcd,num;
```

That done, I currently have issues when trying to nest this query inside another for just filtering the query based on a specific SubProcessID like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Subprocess_has_Characteristic` WHERE `SubProcessID` = 'SubProcessID1'
```

If I use this query alone the results are shown like this:

**ID       SubprocessID       CharacteristicID**

---

ID1     SubprocessID1     CharacteristicID1

ID11    SubprocessID1    CharacteristicID5

ID2     SubprocessID1     CharacteristicID2

---

Whereas I need it to show like this:

**ID       SubprocessID       CharacteristicID**

---

ID1     SubprocessID1     CharacteristicID1

ID2     SubprocessID1     CharacteristicID2

ID11    SubprocessID1    CharacteristicID5

---

This is what I'm trying to achieve nesting the two MySQL Queries previously mentioned. Unfortunately I've had no luck in getting my code to work.

The query I've been trying to use is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `Subprocess_has_Characteristic` WHERE `SubProcessID` = 'SubProcessID1' IN (
SELECT *,substring(ID, 1, 13) as bcd, 
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(ID, 14, 20),UNSIGNED INTEGER) 
AS num from `Subprocess_has_Characteristic` order by bcd,num);
```

This unfortunately yields the following error:

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Is there any error in my MySQL syntax?

*EDIT*

I changed the example to a more precise case scenario; hope this helps in understanding what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: your question is not clear  ... try update the question adding a proper sample of data and the expected  result

Comment: change the last 2 chars from **order by bcd,num;)** to **order by bcd,num);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Length()` function returns the number of characters in the `ID`.So the `ID` with single digits will be sorted first and so on...

```
SELECT * FROM `Subprocess_has_Characteristic`
 WHERE `SubProcessID` = 'SubProcessID1'     
 ORDER BY LENGTH(ID), ID;
```

Comment: The first query didn't seem to order the elements in the right order. Your second query works 100% though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do have an error in your SQL syntax (multiple errors actually).

Here are the salient points

- your where clause contains 2 operators (`=` and `IN`), which one do you actually mean to use?
- the subquery is returning multiple columns, but should only return one for the `IN` operator
- the semi-colon (`;`) is in the wrong place

I am afraid I not quote understand what your trying to achieve, so I am unable to help you with the proper corrections.

Comment: I edited the post to hopefully make the issue easier to understand. Corrected the (`;`) and I'm not quite sure I understand the issue with the 2 operators for the `WHERE` clause, as the `=` is meant to work for the first query and the `IN` to introduce the nested query. Tried replacing the `IN` to a `FROM ()` nesting the other query but that doesn't seem to help.